# Remove special character in front of string pentaho

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-spoon, pentaho-data-integration

i tried to do to remove special characters in string

```
--repeating-repeating
```

What i want is that the string would become

```
repeating-repeating
```

I used string operations and replace in strings, but it would remove all the dash line `-`
What should i do then?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a “replace in string” step, with option “use Regex” set to Y.

Comment: but i only wanted in front of the string instead all of it

Comment: Hence, a regex. Write the correct pattern and the search and replace will do what you want.